# O que fazer quando o codigo é comprido e tu não quer mostrar alguma parte?

Tags: debate, suporte

Estive com um certo problema para explicar uma pergunta envolvendo front-end. E geralmente, perguntas desse tipo tu usa um interpretador online para executar os exemplos de front-end. Mas como posso perguntar, sendo que no meu front-end tem o back-end envolvido também (como o exemplo executando funcionalidades do PHP)? Também a partes do codigo que não gostaria de mostrar, e também tem a inclusão de outros arquivos como o header, footer e o sidebar. Qual é a alternativa para mim fazer uma boa pergunta e me ajudar a solucionar o problema?

Comment: Se o problema é no front, não precisa do back, você pode gerar informações falsas condizentes com as que o back geraria. Se tem códigos que não quer mostrar, ok, basta estruturar o exemplo que simule exatamente o mesmo comportamento do seu código original. Na minha curta experiência no site mostrou que o problema não é o processo de criar o exemplo, mas sim de entender o problema. Na grande maioria a pessoa não analisa o próprio problema a fundo e se sente na liberdade de perguntar de qualquer forma. É comum ver coisas como "CSS está deixando o texto vermelho" e com a tag PHP junto.